# Модификация .class файлов перед упаковкой

Tags: java, android, android-gradle

Всем привет.

В рамках одной из задач возникла необходимость сделать простенькую защиту от взлома для одного из приложений на Android.
**Что имеем**: готовое приложение, среда разработки `Android Studio`, система сборки `gradle`.
**Что надо**: после компиляции java-файла и получения соответствующего ему class-файла необходимо вызвать некий скрипт (или выполнить код), который модифицирует полученный файл и только потом он уже пойдет в jar/dex/apk. Делать это надо для всех файлов, кроме одного - кастомного ClassLoader, который будет после загрузки class-файла производить обратные изменения и только потом скармливать JVM.
**Вопрос**: Как это настроить в gradle?

P.S. Я знаю про ProGuard, про native, про то, что можно выдрать при желании из памяти нормальный код class-файла. Но задача такая вот...

Comment: Пара предостережений. Если обработка сделает класс невалидным, то конвертация в DEX не пройдёт. А реверснуть можно будет легко, посмотрев код Вашего ClassLoader'а.

Comment: Реверснуть будет тяжелей, если класлоадер будет выполнять нативный код). Класс невалидным станет разумеется. Для обычной явы это не проблема. Как быть для андроида тогда? Мне надо, что бы после dex2jar-а были недекомпилируемые class-файлы.

Comment: @АлександрМартынцев это сомнительная вещь... я уже знаю как достать ваши исходники =) посмотрите как реализованы пакеры с нативным ClassLoader. Вы видимо свой пакер и хотите =)